# How to use the join keyword to join two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, keyword

I do not  know how to use the join keyword in the following situation. I have two tables and i need to join them in one table. This is the code

```
use DEV

select top 10 
    Casa_de_marcat, 
    Numar_bon, 
    Data_bon 
from antetBonuri 
where Casa_de_marcat=1
order by Data_bon desc

use DEV

select top 10 
    Total, 
    Data, 
    Ora, 
    Vinzator 
from bp
order by Data desc
```

these are the results from the two tables

```
Casa_de_marcat Numar_bon   Data_bon
-------------- ----------- -----------------------
1              NULL        2018-05-12 00:00:00.000
1              1           2018-04-13 00:00:00.000
1              NULL        2018-03-16 00:00:00.000
1              NULL        2018-03-16 00:00:00.000
1              1           2018-02-16 00:00:00.000
1              1           2018-02-05 00:00:00.000
1              NULL        2018-02-05 00:00:00.000
1              NULL        2018-02-05 00:00:00.000
1              10          2017-11-02 00:00:00.000
1              NULL        2017-09-29 00:00:00.000

(10 rows affected)

Total                  Data                    Ora    Vinzator
---------------------- ----------------------- ------ ----------
12                     2019-11-15 00:00:00.000 1150   naomi     
12                     2019-11-15 00:00:00.000 1150   naomi     
82                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1035   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1038   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1043   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1044   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1044   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1053   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1105   MIHAI     
12                     2019-10-17 00:00:00.000 1108   MIHAI     

(10 rows affected)
```

the final results should be all the above columns joined in a single table , the order does not count.
And yes, my bad, im using SQL server

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (top 10 looks like MS SQL Server code.)

Comment: JOIN how? Show us the two results, and the combined result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Can you please share your expected result if possible?

Answer (score 0):

A `FULL JOIN` technically does what you want:

```
select ab.*, bp.*
from (select top 10 Casa_de_marcat, Numar_bon, Data_bon 
      from antetBonuri 
      where Casa_de_marcat = 1
      order by Data_bon desc
     ) ab full join
     (select top 10 Total, Data, Ora,  Vinzator 
      from bp
      order by Data desc
     ) bp
     on 1 = 0;  -- never matches
```

There are no obvious `JOIN` keys.

This produces 20 rows with all the columns.  In each row, one of the sets of columns (per subquery) will all be `NULL`.

That appears to be what you are asking for.  I'm not sure how useful this is.  Or why you would prefer using `JOIN` rather than `UNION ALL` to get this.

EDIT:

It also strikes me that you might want 10 rows side-by-side.  If so, then use `row_number()`:

```
select ab.Casa_de_marcat, ab.Numar_bon, ab.Data_bon,
       bp.Total, bp.Data, bp.Ora, bp.Vinzator
from (select top 10 Casa_de_marcat, Numar_bon, Data_bon,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from antetBonuri 
      where Casa_de_marcat = 1
      order by Data_bon desc
     ) ab full join
     (select top 10 Total, Data, Ora,  Vinzator, 
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from bp
      order by Data desc
     ) bp
     on ab.seqnum = bp.seqnum;
```

This results in 10 rows with the results "side-by-side".  The rows from the two tables are in an arbitrary order.